# How to rename many dataframe columns efficently to a specific format in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I've a dataframe which each column represents a group age and I need to rename them as "age_index"

e.g:

```
x <- data.frame(x = 20:56, y = 36:72, z =10:46 , stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
index <- 0:2 
age_base <- rep(c("age_"), times = 3) 
age_name <- paste(age_base, index, sep="")
names(x) <- age_name
```

My question is if I've **other variables** (many more) such as weight and height and need to change them to that format "var_index" how can I do this without having to repeat `paste(rep(c("var_index"), times = n), index, sep = "")` for each one of them.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate column names in data.frame

Comment: If you need to change based on multiple elements `rep(c("age_", "weight_", "height_"), each = 3)`

Comment: If there are different replications, that needs to be changed as well.   Please check my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of them have the same replications, then just concatenate the prefix names as a `vector`, and use `each` instead of `times`

```
paste0(rep(c("age_", "weight_", "height_"), each = 3), index)
#[1] "age_0"    "age_1"    "age_2"  
#[4] "weight_0" "weight_1" "weight_2" 
#[7] "height_0" "height_1" "height_2"
```

Note that the `index` vector is of length 3 and it gets recycled to the length of the `rep`licated.

---

If instead, we have different number of `rep`lications, use `times` (by default it will be used)

```
v1 <- c(2, 4, 3)
paste0(rep(c("age_", "weight_", "height"), v1),
       sequence(v1) - 1)
#[1] "age_0"    "age_1"   
#[3] "weight_0" "weight_1" "weight_2" "weight_3"
#[7] "height0"  "height1"  "height2"
```